# Microsoft Teams tab loading app with Auth0

Tags: angular, single-sign-on, single-page-application, microsoft-teams, auth0

I got an angular SPA using Auth0 for authentication. I tried adding it as an app i Microsoft teams and the usual username and password login works fine however, using LinkedIn and Google ended up not working in the actual app but only in the web client version of Teams.

I'm pretty new into the O365 world and also doing apps for teams so I'm not really sure where to start looking.

My manifest looks like the following:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/json-schemas/teams/v1.8/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
  "manifestVersion": "1.8",
  "id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "version": "1.0",
  "packageName": "helloTeams",
  "developer": {
    "name": "Contoso",
    "websiteUrl": "https://www.contoso.com",
    "privacyUrl": "",
    "termsOfUseUrl": "",
    "mpnId": "6006813"
  },
  "name": {
    "short": "Hello world",
    "full": "Hello world"
  },
  "description": {
    "short": "Testing!",
    "full": "Testing!"
  },
  "icons": {
    "outline": "icon-outline.png",
    "color": "icon-color.png"
  },
  "accentColor": "#6b009e",
  "configurableTabs": [],
  "staticTabs": [
    {
      "entityId": "XXXXXXXXXXXXX",
      "name": "Contoso",
      "contentUrl": "https://app.contoso.com/",
      "scopes": [
        "personal"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "bots": [],
  "connectors": [],
  "composeExtensions": [],
  "permissions": [
    "identity",
    "messageTeamMembers"
  ],
  "validDomains": [
    "app.contoso.com", "*.google.com", "*.linkedin.com"
  ],
  "showLoadingIndicator": false,
  "isFullScreen": false
}
```

I've tried both with doing the login flow for google and linkedin with redirect and with pop-up window no of them works in the Teams desktop application (windows). Any clues of where to start look would be much appreciated.

Comment: I haven't done AuthO auth like this with Teams, so I'm just throwing this out in case it can help, but I'm not sure that wildcard domains are allowed in the "validDomains".

Comment: Yes. that seemed to be the problem with the manifest file. Thank you!

Comment: ok great, glad you came right. Please upvote the comment so it's recognised.

Comment: @DanielKassell curious if you can provide some sample code or a description of how you setup this up in Auth0? Any links you can provide on the setup? I'm trying to do the same thing but I'm just getting a blank screen when I preview in Teams. I'm sure I'm missing a configuration, but just not sure since I haven't been able to find any documentation for this sort of setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem in the manifest file. It did not support wildcards in the domain name.

Next problem is that Teams application is doing an iframe and Google and LinkedIn doesn't support iframed logins. Tried to do the pop-up flow instead but then it opens the popup in the default browser instead of teams.

Follow up question: Is there an easy way to have the pop-up be opened in Teams? Otherwise it feels like I need to create a completely new login flow just for teams.

Comment: I'd suggest asking this as a separate question, but yes, Teams is a bit different because it launches it's OWN popup when you trigger the authentication flow. Funny as it sounds, you want to do the "redirect" flow, and it happens _inside this popup_.

Comment: Teams support only IFrame pages. This is by design. And for authentication, Teams will launch a popup and authenticate the user withoot redirecting to browser. Could you please check this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/authentication/authentication) for more Info.